# why booting APs needs an indirect call in the mit6.828 example OS kernel?

Tags: assembly, x86, operating-system, osdev, multiprocessor

I'm studying mit6.828 course, I don't understand why it must indirect call when booting APs in lab4. I try to direct call `call mp_main`(source code: `movl $mp_main, %eax; call *%eax`), but it causes triple fault. Here is part of the source code

```
###################################################################
# entry point for APs
###################################################################

# Each non-boot CPU ("AP") is started up in response to a STARTUP
# IPI from the boot CPU.  Section B.4.2 of the Multi-Processor
# Specification says that the AP will start in real mode with CS:IP
# set to XY00:0000, where XY is an 8-bit value sent with the
# STARTUP. Thus this code must start at a 4096-byte boundary.
#
# Because this code sets DS to zero, it must run from an address in
# the low 2^16 bytes of physical memory.
#
# boot_aps() (in init.c) copies this code to MPENTRY_PADDR (which
# satisfies the above restrictions).  Then, for each AP, it stores the
# address of the pre-allocated per-core stack in mpentry_kstack, sends
# the STARTUP IPI, and waits for this code to acknowledge that it has
# started (which happens in mp_main in init.c).
#
# This code is similar to boot/boot.S except that
#    - it does not need to enable A20
#    - it uses MPBOOTPHYS to calculate absolute addresses of its
#      symbols, rather than relying on the linker to fill them


    # Switch to the per-cpu stack allocated in boot_aps()
    movl    mpentry_kstack, %esp
    movl    $0x0, %ebp       # nuke frame pointer

    # Call mp_main().  (Exercise for the reader: why the indirect call?)
    movl    $mp_main, %eax
    call    *%eax
```

I don't konw how to debug with gdb in multi-cpu especially at boot, but the entry.S is similar to this code and it's easy to debug. Here is entry.S key code

```
    mov $relocated, %eax
    jmp *%eax   
relocated:
    movl    $0x0,%ebp           # nuke frame pointer
```

Below is the gdb output of the correct code. Before `jmp *%eax`, eip is low address, but after it eip is high address. And the next instruction is `mov $0, %ebp`.

```
(gdb) si
=> 0x10002d:    jmp    *%eax
0x0010002d in ?? ()
(gdb) info reg eax eip
eax            0xf010002f   -267386833
eip            0x10002d 0x10002d
(gdb) si
=> 0xf010002f:  mov    $0x0,%ebp
0xf010002f in ?? ()
(gdb) info reg eax eip
eax            0xf010002f   -267386833
eip            0xf010002f   0xf010002f
```

If we change to direct `call relocated` instead of `mov $relocated, %eax; jmp *%eax`, it causes a triple fault, and gdb output:

```
(gdb) 
=> 0x100028:    call   0x10002d
0x00100028 in ?? ()
(gdb) info reg eip 
eip            0x100028 0x100028
(gdb) si
=> 0x100028:    call   0x10002d
0x00100028 in ?? ()
```

If we look at objdump output

```
    call relocated
f0100028:   e8 00 00 00 00          call   f010002d <relocated>

f010002d <relocated>:
relocated:

    # Clear the frame pointer register (EBP)
    # so that once we get into debugging C code,
    # stack backtraces will be terminated properly.
    movl    $0x0,%ebp           # nuke frame pointer
f010002d:   bd 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%ebp
```

Here both virtual address [0xf0000000, 0xf0000000+4MB) and [0, 4MB) are mapped to physical address [0, 4MB)

I want to know how indirect call changes this. the full code you can find in github just search 'mit6.828' in kern/entry.S and kern/mpentry.S

Comment: Do you know what the constraints are for near calls?

Comment: I suppose the code is relocated but `mp_main` always resides at a fixed address.

Comment: @fuz: According to the comments, (a copy of) this code runs in real mode from a different `CS:0000` for each core, so the relative distance to `mp_main` will be different for each core.  (Different IP depending on the CS value if it's not part of the replicated code).  Comments say there's a mechanism that fills in absolute addresses of symbols, but apparently not relative.  I would have thought it would make sense to use a far jmp or `call ptr16:32` to switch to a 32-bit code segment in protected mode along with jumping to a common location, but IDK what `mp_main` still has to do.

Comment: Change it to a direct one. See what breaks.

Comment: I don't really see a point in using an indirect call. Near direct calls are relative and if that's really 16-bit code they can only use a 16-bit offset, but so is for the `call *%eax` which fault if `eax` > 64KiB.  `mov $mp_main, %eax` it is easy to fix but, again, a call would be equally easy to fix. Even if this code is duplicated for each AP (which is unnecessary), I still don't see the point. Unless they cannot fix relative calls because maybe they can only fix loads and stores. Who knows? Maybe it's because the call is "external" and the linker doesn't fully support it

Comment: Does BOCHS support emulating a multi-core system?  If so, use it; its built-in debugger is probably better for this (and is aware of real-mode segmentation).  And can probably tell you *why* you triple-faulted.