# Is there a way to jump to long mode using an indirect jump?

Tags: assembly, x86, operating-system, osdev, multiprocessor

I am writing an operating system and have just started the other CPUs, so I am in assembly on each now. I have set up long mode and now I just need to perform a far jump. However, when I try to do any form of direct jump, I receive a triple fault. I have tried using -d int in qemu, and of course info registers but I cannot find why. I've spent a long time searching for the answer when I came across this stack overflow question:

[The Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66343732/why-booting-aps-needs-an-indirect-call-in-the-mit6-828-example-os-kernel)

This question is exactly the same as my first question, however no-one has answered it. This did, however, confirm my suspicions that I cannot perform direct jumps and must do an indirect one, which is what I am asking here.

I tried to figure out what caused the triple fault using debugging tools in qemu and gdb but eventually found that stack overflow post. As my assembly is not great (I code more in C), I am wondering how I should go about this problem I have the code:

`jmp 0x8:to_target(ap_trampoline_64)`

However, how would I turn this into an indirect jump? I have tried many things. Unfortunately, I cannot provide a minimal reproducible example because I would have to provide my whole operating system! Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: An indirect jump won't solve your problem. Both would still be absolute jumps. Instead verify your instruction is assembled correctly, the memory is mapped properly and that you are in fact jumping to where want to.

Comment: Using an indirect jump should not make a difference.  But if you want to try it, arrange address and segment into a 10 byte structure in memory and do a far indirect jump with a pointer to it.

Comment: (From 32 bit mode you should use a 6 byte structure of course).

Comment: See if the core that is performing the jump can read memory at that address. If you get a triple fault on the read you need to check your MMU setup. I'd bet the page is not mapped on that core. 

Also, consider setting up some flavor of fault handling to dump the exception.

Comment: Don't worry guys, I solved it. It turned out that my GDT was loaded incorrectly, and also I am now using a far return to jump to long mode. Thanks a lot!